# crash in simulator but iphone when I use dispatch_aplly

Tags: ios, crash, dispatch

When I user dispatch_apply to add some data to nscountset,I get a crash in simulator but iphone. And get a message "-[__NSArrayI isEqual:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x60000024c5a0"   ,I can not find how it happen.

```
CGSize thumbSize = CGSizeMake(200,200);   
NSCountedSet *cls2 = [NSCountedSet setWithCapacity:thumbSize.width * thumbSize.height];
dispatch_apply(thumbSize.width, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(size_t index) {
    int x = (int)index;
    for (int y = 0; y < thumbSize.height; y++) {
        if(y<x){
            continue;
        }
        int offset = 4*(x*y);
        int red = data[offset];
        int green = data[offset+1];
        int blue = data[offset+2];
        int alpha = data[offset+3];
        NSArray *clr2 = @[@(red),@(green),@(blue),@(alpha)];
        [cls2 addObject:clr2];
    }

});
```

crash in [cls2 addobject:clr2];The log is "-[__NSArrayI isEqual:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x60000024c5a0".
And There are all Code In My function,I want get the mostColor in a Image.

```
CGSize thumbSize = CGSizeMake(200, 200);

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, thumbSize.width, thumbSize.height, 8, thumbSize.width * 4, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

CGRect drawRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, thumbSize.width, thumbSize.height);

CGContextDrawImage(context, drawRect, self.CGImage);

CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
unsigned char *data = CGBitmapContextGetData(context);
if (data == NULL)
{
    return nil;
}
NSCountedSet *cls2 = [NSCountedSet setWithCapacity:thumbSize.width * thumbSize.height];
dispatch_apply(thumbSize.width, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(size_t index) {
    int x = (int) index;
    for (int y = 0; y < thumbSize.height; y++)
    {

        if (y < x)
        {
            continue;
        }
        int offset = 4 * (x * y);
        int red = data[offset];
        int green = data[offset + 1];
        int blue = data[offset + 2];
        int alpha = data[offset + 3];
        NSArray *clr3 = @[@(red), @(green), @(blue), @(alpha)];
        [cls2 addObject:clr3];
    }

});

CGContextRelease(context);

NSEnumerator *enumerator = [cls2 objectEnumerator];
NSArray *curColor = nil;
NSArray *maxColor = nil;
NSUInteger maxCount = 0;
while ((curColor = [enumerator nextObject]) != nil)
{
    NSUInteger tmpCount = [cls2 countForObject:curColor];
    if (tmpCount < maxCount) {
        continue;
    }

    maxCount = tmpCount;
    maxColor = curColor;
}

NSLog(@"colors: RGB A %f %d %d  %d",[maxColor[0] floatValue],[maxColor[1] intValue],[maxColor[2] intValue],[maxColor[3] intValue]);

return [UIColor colorWithRed:([maxColor[0] intValue]/255.0f) green:([maxColor[1] intValue]/255.0f) blue:([maxColor[2] intValue]/255.0f) alpha:([maxColor[3] intValue]/255.0f)];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSCountedSet` is not thread safe - [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html). Attempting to mutate one from concurrent threads is going to give unpredictable results - as you have found.

Either use a simple `for` loop without a `dispatch_apply`, dispatched on a background thread if required, to process your data, or protect your `NSCountedSet` update by dispatching it on a serial dispatch queue.

Comment: I want to reduce the time to add obj to NSCountedSet,if I use serial dispatch queue.How can I do to reduce the time.

Comment: Oh,I understand what you say.I will try it.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it a bit more, since the order of updating the counted set isn't important you could even dispatch the update asynchronously on a serial dispatch queue, but then you would need some other method of tracking when the set was completely updated - perhaps a dispatch_group